# Web performance test with database

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

I'm creating a web performance test in Visual Studio 2013 which basically should load random product pages... Until today I've been using a CSV file as datasource, however I want to change this to start using a database instead.

Setting up the connection to the database was very easy. However, the products in my table have a column "IsSearchable", which in the case of being false, I don't want my tests to pick up these products. I can't find any way on how to make any conditions on what to select from the table. Is this even possible or would the solution be to either create a separate table for the tests or just stick with CSV files?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: To make things more clear: I am trying to alter the web performance test's  SQL query to include a WHERE clause in their SELECT. Is this possible? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: You could also create a view in the database to solve this. Sorry I din't know web perfomance testing is part of visual studio, I thought you created your own.

Comment: Great idea, that would be a way of solving this. If you mind updating your other answer I can mark it as answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Web performance test is part of visual studio.

I'm not sure if it's possible to change the generated query, but you could however create a view in the database to solve this issue.

Old Answer:
Assuming you are using some kind of SQL, and that you use a SELECT Statement to get the Data, you can just extend the SELECT statement with a WHERE clause.

So it would look similiar to this:

```
SELECT [column1],[column2] FROM [Table] WHERE IsSearchable = TRUE.
```

For more information about the WHERE clause, see this link for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188047%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the consideration, however I do know about SQL. This specific question is about web performance test and if there would be possible to alter web performance test's own SQL query to include such a WHERE clause.